# Sort and limit capping results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

I got a collection containing 20,000+ documents where only id is indexed.
I'm want to query using limit and a sort, but the limit kicks in before the sort.

```
collection.find({})
    .sort({kick_return_yards: -1}) // desc largest to smallest
    .limit(500)
    .toArray (err, records){

    });
```

kick_return_yards is a positive whole number. I know I have values for this number ranging from 0 to 177.

With above query I only get documents where kick_return_yards is 0. So it seems sort is executed after limit.

How do I get around this hoop?

Comment: I don't believe you. Which driver are you using? Looks like it could be node native. Show us some documents you expect. My money says these values are in fact "strings".

Comment: @Blakes Seven: And you shouldn't! Because apparently (and here comes the excuse) due to surrounding business logic something went haywire. I stripped down to the bare basic - and voila it works as per stated by the documentation. Sorry for the inconvenience.